# How to add mount_afp to system startup

Tags: 13.04, startup

I have a feeling this is a really dumb question but......

I am running Ubuntu 13.04 and I am running the following command to connect to my apple time capsule

```
    mount_afp afp://user:password@server_host_or_ip/Data ~/capsule
```

I currently run this from the terminal after I login but I would like to run this automatically at startup

As an Ubuntu newbie I'm stumped as to where to look to do this

Any / all help appreciated

@thefourtheye - here's the contents of rc.local

```
    #!/bin/sh -e
    mount_afp afp://user:password@server_host_or_ip/Data ~/capsule
    exit 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add

```
mount_afp afp://user:password@server_host_or_ip/Data ~/capsule
```

to

```
/etc/rc.local
```

file. This will make sure that mount_afp command is executed whenever you login.

Comment: Thanks for the help - I've edited /etc/rc.local as suggested but the command isn't running during startup - is there anyway of checking what is causing the problem?

Comment: Could you please post the contents of your `/etc/rc.local`?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply - I'll post that this evening when I get home - this is a fresh install of Ubuntu so the only additional line of code I've added to rc.local is the mount_afp command and I added this above the end 0 statement